# How to make an object take and store an Array of arbitrary, but compile-time known size?

Tags: c++, oop, embedded

## Background

For an embedded project, I want a class that takes a list of structs. This list is known at compile-time, so I shouldn't have to resort to dynamic memory allocation for this.

However, how do I make a struct/class that encapsulates this array without having to use its size as a template parameter?

## Templates

My first idea was to do exactly that:

```
struct Point {
    const uint16_t a;
    const double b;
};

template<size_t n>
struct Profile {
    Array<Point, n> points;

    Profile(const Array<Point, n> &points) : points(points) {}
};
```

Here, `Profile` is the class that stores/encapsulates the array of points (the 2-member structs). `n`, the size of the array, is a template parameter.

I'm using [this](https://github.com/janelia-arduino/Array) implementation of Array, similar to `std::array`, btw, because I don't have access to the STL on this embedded platform.

However, no I have another class that uses this `Profile` that now also has to be templated because `Profile` is templated with the size of the array:

```
template<size_t n>
class Runner {
private:
    const Profile<n> profile;
public:
    Runner(const Profile<n> &profile) : profile(profile) {};

    void foo() {
        for(auto point : profile.points) {
            // do something
        }
    }
};
```

As can be seen, this `Runner` class operates on a `Profile` and iterates over it. Having to template `Runner` is not that much of an issue by itself, but this `Runner` in turn is used by another class in my project, because this other class calls `Runner::foo()`. Now I have to template that class as well! And classes that use that class, etc.

That's getting out of hand! What started with just one template parameter to specify the size, now propagates through my entire application. Therefore, I don't think this is a good solution.

## Question

Is there a way to 'hide' the size of the array in `Profile` or `Runner`? Runner only needs to iterate over it, so the size should in principle only affect its implementation, not its public interface. How would I do that, though?

Also, can I avoid having to manually specify `n` at all, and just pass an array to `Profile`'s constructor and let the compiler figure out how big it is? At compile-time, of course. I feel like this should be possible (given this array is known at compile-time), but I don't know how exactly.

## Other approaches

### Macros

I could write a macro like

```
#define n 12
```

and include that in both the `Profile.h` and the place where I instantiate a `Profile`. This feels dirty though, I and would like to avoid macros.

### Vector

I could avoid this fuss by just using a `std::vector` (or equivalent) instead, but that is allocated at run-time on the heap, which I would like to avoid here since it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: How many different sizes will you need?

Comment: Also, this implementation of array seems to allow storing less than max elements (unlike `std::array`), perhpas it would be enough to just use the maximum size of the array you will ever use?

Comment: At which point do you actually know the size of the array? If eg a `Runner` always needs a `Profile` with an array of size `12` then it can use `Profile<12>` if you need `Runner`s with different sized `Profile`s then making `Runner` a template doesn't sound too bad

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Don't really know yet. I just wanted a `Profile` class that works with an arbitrary size.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number The idea is that `Runner` takes `Profile`s no matter their size. `Runner` needs to iterate over it, but apart from that, its behaviour is always the same. The class using `Runner` and calling `Runner::foo()` doesn't need to know the size. The problem with templating `Runner` is that the class using `Runner` also needs to be templated, and the classes using that, etc.

Comment: is inheritance an option?

Comment: What's the reason for not using a plain old array of size `n` where `n` is a plain old integer constant? Too easy? Too readable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to 'hide' the size of the array in Profile or Runner?

Yes. The solution is indirection. Instead of storing the object directly, you can point to it. You don't need to know the size of what you're pointing at.

A convenient solution is to point into dynamic storage (for example `std::vector`) because it allows you to "bind" the lifetime of the dynamically sized object to a member. That's not necessary in general, and you can use automatic storage instead. However, in that case you cannot bind the lifetime of the pointed object, and you must be very careful to not let the pointed object be destroyed before you stop using it.

The indirection can be done at whatever level you prefer. If you do it at the lowest level, you simply store the array outside of `Profile`. In fact, if all that profile does is contain an array, then you don't need a class for it. Use a generic `span`:

```
struct Runner {
    span<const Point> profile;
    void foo() {
        for(auto point : profile) {
            // do something
        }
    }
};

Point points[] {
    // ... number of points doesn't matter
};
Runner runner {
    .profile = points,
};
```

---

By `span`, I mean something like `std::span`. If you cannot use the standard library, then use another implementation. It's basically just a pointer and size, with convenient template constructor.

---

To clarify, you can pick any two, but you cannot have all three of these:

1. Lifetime of the array bound to the class (safe)
2. No compiletime constant size
3. No dynamic storage

- 1,2 (no 3) = `std::vector`, RAII
- 1,3 (no 2) = `std::array`, templates, no indirection
- 2,3 (no 1) = `std::span`, be careful with lifetimes

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a good solution! What is the reason this works? The fact that (unlike `std::array`) it doesn't make the size a part of its type ?

Comment: @Compizfox It works because it's not trying to store the array inside the class. It's stored separately, with a separate lifetime.

Comment: I see. But even in my approach, I could ditch `Profile` as a container around the array (like you did) and only take/store a pointer/reference to the array in `Runner`. In that case, it doesn't store the array, yet it becomes part of `Runner`'s type (leading to the exact same problem). With `std::span`, I avoid that, right?

Comment: @Compizfox `I could ditch Profile as a container around the array (like you did) and only take/store a pointer/reference to the array in Runner` That's precisely what I'm suggesting as the solution (well not a reference since that wouldn't work). `std::span` is just a pointer and a size combined.

Comment: I got that, I was just dissecting *why* your solution works and mine didn't ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'll expand on this comment:

> The idea is that Runner takes Profiles no matter their size. Runner needs to iterate over it, but apart from that, its behaviour is always the same. The class using Runner and calling Runner::foo() doesn't need to know the size. The problem with templating Runner is that the class using Runner also needs to be templated, and the classes using that, etc.

This is only a problem when the class is using the templated `Runner` directly. It has more dependencies than it actually needs. If it doesn't need to know about the size of the array, then it should not know about the size of the array. If runtime polymorphism is an option you can add a base class that allows accessing the array elements, but doesn't need to know anything about the arrays size. The following is only a sketch:

```
#include <iostream>

struct RunnerInterface {
    virtual int* begin() = 0;
    virtual int* end() = 0;
    virtual ~RunnerInterface(){}
};

template <unsigned size>
struct Runner : RunnerInterface {
    int data[size];
    int* begin() override { return data; }
    int* end() override { return data+size; } // pointer one past the end if fine (it won't get dereferenced)
};

void foo(RunnerInterface& ri) {
    for (auto it = ri.begin(); it != ri.end(); ++it){
        *it = 42;
    }
}

void bar(RunnerInterface& ri){
    for (auto it = ri.begin(); it != ri.end(); ++it){
        std::cout << *it;
    }
}

int main() {
    Runner<42> r;
    foo(r);
    bar(r);
}
```

Now if a class needs a `Runner` member, they store a `std::unique_ptr<RunnerInterface>` and only on construction you need to decide for the size of the array (though you still need to decide for the size somewhere).

Comment: I agree that the class using `Runner` shouldn't need to know about `n`. But with the template approach, this happens inevitably, right? The template parameter 'propagates'. Unless there is a way to 'break this chain' using type erasure or something. But I'm not sure about that. I would like to avoid runtime polymorphism.